# fetchall() psycopg2 returning empty list

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm trying to make a query using psycopg2. I know the query below works when I query it in pgAdmin, but for some reason retchall() is returning an empty list.

I've used the same formatting before in other queries and been able to fetch the results so I'm wodnering if there's a formatting issue or something. I don't get any errors when executing it just returns an empty list.

I'm also using DictCursor so I can reference the query by keys: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#dictionary-like-cursor

```
    import db_funcs.DB as DB
    import time
    import psycopg2.extras
    import json
    import sys
    
    def route_export(stops, project_list):
        try:
            cursor, connection = DB.dbInit()
    
            dict_cur = connection.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
    
            for project in project_list:
                drivers = []
                stops = {"stops": stops[project]}
    
                dict_cur.execute(
                    """SELECT rp.route_project_id, rp.route_name, rp.driver_id, rp.route_date,
                    d.driver_id, d.name as driver_name, d.start_location_coords, 
                    d.start_location_add, d.end_location_coords, d.end_location_add, 
                    d.shift_start, d.shift_end, d.phone_number, d.speed, d.capacity, d.types, 
                    d.breaks, d.delivery_area_id 
                    FROM route_project rp
                    JOIN driver d 
                    ON rp.driver_id = d.driver_id
                    WHERE TO_DATE(LEFT(route_date,10),'YYYY-MM-DD') >= NOW()
                    and route_name = %s """,
                    (project,),
                )
    
                rows = dict_cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: are you getting the empty list while running in debug mode?

Comment: What is `project` exactly? I seldom had to use something like `project = str(project)` to pass a value to PostgreSQL...

Comment: Sorry i should have removed `project = str(project)` that is currently doing nothing as its already a string. I was trying to see if that was the issue but `project` is already a string. I've edited the post

Comment: BTW, `WHERE TO_DATE(LEFT(route_date,10),'YYYY-MM-DD') >= NOW()` is a terrible where clause: you call a function on every row, and prevent the optimizer to use a possible index on `route_date`. `WHERE route_date >= TO_CHAR(NOW(), '...')` is always better. And how is `route_date` actually declared and formatted?

Comment: `route_date` is stored as a string (but the formatting is "2020-08-18T06:00:00.000Z") - thanks for the recommendation! sorry i'm not super experienced with SQL, why does that improve the efficiency?

Comment: @Tasnuva ya it's empty as soon as I call it

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this running, see if you get output?

```
import db_funcs.DB as DB
import time
import psycopg2.extras
import json
import sys

def route_export(stops, project_list):
try:
    cursor, connection = DB.dbInit()

    dict_cur = connection.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)

    for project in project_list:
        drivers = []
        project = str(project)
        stops = {"stops": stops[project]}

        q = dict_cur.execute(
            'SELECT rp.route_project_id, rp.route_name, rp.driver_id, rp.route_date,
            d.driver_id, d.name as driver_name, d.start_location_coords, 
            d.start_location_add, d.end_location_coords, d.end_location_add, 
            d.shift_start, d.shift_end, d.phone_number, d.speed, d.capacity, d.types, 
            d.breaks, d.delivery_area_id 
            FROM route_project rp
            JOIN driver d 
            ON rp.driver_id = d.driver_id
            WHERE TO_DATE(LEFT(route_date,10),"YYYY-MM-DD") >= NOW()
            and route_name = ?', [project])

        rows = q.fetchall()
```

Comment: i get a syntaxt error when i try : `psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at end of input LINE 10: and route_name = ?`

Comment: may be its bcas of the single quotes. can you try once again now. I edited the query now.

Comment: unfortunately, i still get the same error. unless im mistaken, i think psycopg2 requires the `%s` formatting (https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html).